# Получить значения в диапазоне excel Golang excelize

Tags: golang, excel, файловый-ввод-вывод

У меня есть excel таблица в которой есть данные, я использую библиотеку excelize для работы. Хочу получить данные в диапазоне, например, с A2 до D8. Но я в документации не нашёл такого. Может кто-то работал с этим?  В доке я нашёл только поиск по столбцам, строкам и поиск в определённой ячейке (GetRows, GetCols, GetCellValue). но там нельзя ставить диапазон значений.

Comment: `rows, err := f.GetRows("Sheet1")`,  а потом `for i, row := range rows {
  if i >= 1 && i <= 6 {
   fmt.Println(row[0:4])
  }
 }` 
перебор строк и вывода столбцов 0 до 3 для каждой строки в диапазоне строк 2 до 7.

Comment: Гениально, я мучился с этим долго. Спасибо

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import (
    "fmt"

    "github.com/360EntSecGroup-Skylar/excelize"
)

func main() {
    f, err := excelize.OpenFile("test.xlsx")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }

    rows, err := f.GetRows("Sheet1")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }

    for i, row := range rows {
        if i >= 1 && i <= 6 {
            fmt.Println(row[0:4])
        }
    }
}
```

В этом примере открываем файл test.xlsx, затем используем метод `GetRows` для получения строк из листа `Sheet1`. Затем мы используем цикл for для перебора строк и вывода столбцов 0 до 3 для каждой строки в диапазоне строк 2 до 7.